# Angularjs search constant value+ value from textbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

Is it possible to search value by some constant value + value come from textbox
In AngularJS filter, I am searching for no. of goals. Let's say I am looking for total no. of goals 4, it is giving me unnecessary result also like wherever it founds 4 like in match date field.

Is it possible to search for content Total Goals: 7  where Total Goals: is constant and user should enter numeric part only in textbox for searching i.e 7

Attaching Image for better clarity

[Click here to see the image for better clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzThr.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which field to be filtered by passing an object with the attribute to the filter. If `totalGoals` is the only key your want the filter to look for, just use

```
<div ng-repeat="match in matches| filter: { totalGoals : yourInPutModel }">
```

If you want to filter by multiple attributes, then you have to write a custom filter like

```
<div ng-repeat="match in matches| filter: yourCustomFilter">
```

and then in controller

```
$scope.yourCustomFilter = function(item) {
    if ((item.totalGoals.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.yourInPutModel) != -1) || (item.anotherAttribute.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.yourInPutModel.toLowerCase()) != -1)) {
        return true;
    }
        return false;
};
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Hi, totalGoals is the static HTML content when i am writting filter:{TotalGoals:score} it is hiding everything as sson a i start writing in text box. here is my code for that part <div ng-repeat="teamname in round.matches | filter:namesearch | filter:year|filter:{TotalGoals:score}">
   <b>Match Date:</b> {{teamname.date}} <br>
  <a ng-href="#!/15/{{teamname.date}}/{{teamname.team1.code}}/{{teamname.team2.code}}">{{teamname.team1.name}} <strong>V/S</strong>
  {{teamname.team2.name}}</a><br>
  <b>TotalGoals</b>{{teamname.score1+teamname.score2}}
 </div>

Comment: can you share how your `round.matches` look like? If possible please create a plunkr. I'll fix there.@pranavgupta